# How can i redirect to my own page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

In wordpress if pages are not found it automatically redirects to 404 page. but i want to redirect to default page which is i created in the same theme (without redirection to 404 page) when the pages are not found. how can i do this?...

Thanks
Ravichandran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit the `404.php` file, and then add the following line:

```
header('location:your-domain-name.com');
```

or you can redirect to some php file also:

```
header('location:default.php');
```

Simple trick. It works for me.

Comment: Freak I need to redirect with in the wordress another file default.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /default.php
```

Add this in .htaccess file

Comment: where do i find .htaccess file in wordpress(which folder)?